# How is work done on an object zero if it’s position is changed with respect to Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, work

A porter lifts a suitcase weighing 20 KG from the platform and puts it on his head 3.0m above the platform. Calculate the work done by the potter on the suitcase.      -Since kinetic energy of the suitcase is zero in both the initial and final states,work done on it is zero.

I want to argue with this statement by considering the suitcase and Earth as the system. Then,is the work done here zero too

https://ibb.co/i3BCGw

Comment: "_Since kinetic energy of the suitcase is zero in both the initial and final states,work done on it is zero._" Is kinetic energy the only form of energy the object can possess?

Comment: Who is telling you the work done is zero?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking when you say "I want to argue with this statement by considering the suitcase and Earth as the system." What argument are you making?

Comment: @sammygerbil I have uploaded a photo of the question and the writer’s solution.

Comment: My internet was so slow I couldn’t upload the image yesterday either so I have gone for a third-party source. I thought not providing this pretext would be fine but it has turned out this way. Sorry all for that

Comment: @DilinFinn The solution says that the **total** work done on the suitcase is zero. The work done by the porter is +392J, the work done by gravity is -392J. See [Work-Energy Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work%E2%80%93energy_principle).

Comment: So,mechanical energy is conserved in which case? Considering- 1)suitcase alone as the system 2)suitcase and potter 3) suitcase and Earth ?

Answer (score 2):

In calculating the work done on an object by a single agent, look at the force(s) exerted by that single agent.

When using the work-energy principle, $\Delta K = W_{\mathrm{net}}$, one must consider the work done by all agents acting on the object. In other words, ask yourself the question, "Are there any forces doing work on the object other than the porter, and is their work non-zero?"

Also, when using the work-energy principle, don't use any potential energies. They might hid sources of work from you because a change in potential energy is equivalent to work done by a conservative force.

Comment: I didn’t get the don’t use potential energy part...

Comment: @DilinFinn The work-energy principle relate kinetic energy change to the work done by *all forces* for an object. Changes in potential energy are matched with work done by conservative forces.  There is no potential energy term the formula for work-energy principle, $\Delta K = W_{\mathrm{net}}$. OTOH, you could replace the conservative force work with potential energy changes and get $\Delta K + \Delta U = W_{\mathrm{non-conservative~forces}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The porter has to counter the weight of suitcase F=mg and moved it up by 3 meters.

so his work: W=F. displacement.

$W= 20*9.81*3$.